# Pass variable to jquery modal popup

Tags: jquery, parameter-passing

I have a list of urls pulled from a mysql database and need to pass a specific url that that was selected to a jQuery modal window.
My issue is I can not figure out how to pass the data and display it in the jQuery modal `div`. Below is my code

```
   <table class="table responsive">
       <thead><th>Topic</th><th></th></thead>
       <tbody>
           <tr>
                      <td>Phone System</td>
                      <td>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default vidurl" data-videourl="https://foobar.s3.amazonaws.com/fake/url/vid.webm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-default">View Video</button>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>Ticket System</td>
                      <td>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default vidurl" data-videourl="https://foobar.s3.amazonaws.com/fake/url/ticketvidinfo.webm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-default">View Video</button>
                      </td>
         </tbody>
    </table>

    <div class="modal fade" id="modal-default">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h4 class="modal-title">Training Video</h4>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <span class="viddata">what to show the video url here </span>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer justify-content-between">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
     </div>
     <!-- /.modal -->
     <!-- below is my attempt to get the data from the button that was clicked and then set it as a variable and then make it load in a span inside the modal -->
     <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".vidurl").click(function(){
               var vidurl = $('.vidurl').data(videourl);
               $('.viddata').text(videourl);
               console.log(videourl);
            });
         });
     </script>
```

Comment: thank you @cytek04 for the edits. I am still looking for how to resolve my issue

Comment: I am now getting a error saying 
 Uncaught ReferenceError: videourl is not defined
I have edited my original message with updated code

Comment: My bad, you need quotes around it. See updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using the `data` attribute quite right. `Data` is a custom attribute. Use it like `data-mycustomname`. Then you can access in jQuery like `$(selector).data("mycustomname")`.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default vidurl" data-url="https://foobar.s3.amazonaws.com/fake/url/vid.webm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-default">View Video</button>
```

Then in your jQuery

```
var vidurl = $('.vidurl').data("url");
```

[html data-* attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_data-.asp)

[jQuery data() method](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/misc_data.asp)